# Equivalent of the old OpenLayers.Layer.Text

Tags: openstreetmap, openlayers-3, csv

I have in the OpenLayers 2 project this construct:

`var pois = new OpenLayers.Layer.Text( "Románské kostely", {
        location:"./kostely.tsv",
        projection: map.displayProjection
    });
    map.addLayer(pois);`

Actually, the ease with which I can create a new layer from just TSV file was one of the reasons why I started to play OpenLayers in the first place.

I have now this as a port to OpenLayers 3:

`new ol.layer.Vector({
                  title: "Románské kostely",
                  source: ol.source.Vector({
                    format: new ol.format.TextTSV(),
                    url: "kostely.tsv"
                  }),
                  style: new ol.style.Style({
                    image: new ol.style.Icon({
                      src: "Ol_icon_blue.png"
                    })
                  })
                })`

Except, obviously, there is no `ol.format.TextTSV()`. The best what I can find in [API](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.7.0/apidoc/ol.format.TextFeature.html) are a way more complicated constructs like `GeoJSON` etc.

Did anybody created an equivalent function for the `OpenLayers 3` API? Or is there a convertor somewhere from the old TSV file to some supported format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work by using [csv2geojson](https://github.com/mapbox/csv2geojson) library provided by MapBox (to convert CSV/TSV to GeoJSON), combined with a `ol.source.Vector` using `ol.format.GeoJSON`.

I produced [an example](http://bl.ocks.org/ThomasG77/d28b7d0ecb5c43ebc368) to illustrate this use case (more complicated than the solution you expected). I didn't bother with the style for the demo and I also use only Vanilla JS (it means "pure JavaScript", no third party library) for Ajax calls.
If you really need a `new ol.format.TextTSV()`, you will need to make your own extension to the core library. You can also ask on the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ol3-dev) if it's on the project roadmap.

Comment: I have tried to imitate your ways in https://matej.ceplovi.cz/kostely/index-new.html but it seems something is still broken. I can see all files (including `kostely.geojson`) downloaded in the network monitor, but OL seems to be really stingy on error messages so nothing shows in the console, although obviously something doesn't wrong. Would you see where I have missed, please?

Comment: You were asking for a TSV solution whereas your sample uses directly GeoJSON. You didn't imitate my way... Hence, it can't work. See this corrected demo to try to understand http://bl.ocks.org/ThomasG77/b4a5703e2751da61952b

Comment: OK, I am here ... https://matej.ceplovi.cz/kostely/index-new.html The last thing I need is to get labels for each feature. There should be permanently displayed (in whatever style, i don't care) property 'title' and even better if on click/hover-over I can get displayed property 'description". Any simple idea how to do it? Thank you SO much for your help so far!

I then get updated the description with the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have  you tried  it in WKT format

var format = new ol.format.WKT();

http://openlayers.org/en/v3.4.0/apidoc/ol.format.WKT.html